# format email body using velocity template?

Tags: java, css, spring, velocity

I am using velocity template to format the mail body. I have below file.

### Sample.vm

```
<html>
<body>

This is an error email<p/>  //This text should be in bold

${exceptionDetails} //This exception details should be in RED font.

</body>
</html>
```

How can i format about text to be in bold and exception details to be in red?

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Use cascading style sheets.

Comment: Is it similar to normal html? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use style declarations to achieve this.

Something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<span style="font-weight:bold">
This is an error email<p/>  //This text should be in bold
</span>
<span style="color:red">
${exceptionDetails} //This exception details should be in RED font.
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

You can read more about this [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3679231).

> When you're coding an HTML email with CSS, make sure that you don't
>   use linked CSS files (.css files attached using link or @import).
>   These are the stylesheets most widely ignored by email clients.
>
> .....

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styles like `<p style="color:red">` as lot of email clients do not support ... tags (including GMail).

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3679231/How-to-Create-Great-HTML-Emails-with-CSS.htm

For other html formattings like bold, italics.. checkout this link
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp